# Working with C Structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm developing some code for a small gaming device I've designed. I've got completely stuck trying to build what is ultimately a Graph of map locations.

I have 2 structs:

```
typedef struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
} point;


typedef struct location {
    const point portal_in;
    const point portal_out;

    const byte *map;
    const byte width;
    const byte height;

    struct location *portals[8];

    point player;

    struct location *return_to;
} location;
```

Each location has a list of other locations that it links to, as well as the location it links from.

I tried to set up the locations like this:

```
location build_locations()
{
    location village = { 
        .portal_in={15, 14}, 
        .portal_out={0, 0}, 
        .map=&VILLAGE[0],
        .width=32,
        .height=16,
        .player={15, 14}, 
        .return_to=0 
    };
    location loc = { 
        .portal_in={8, 7}, 
        .portal_out={11, 10}, 
        .map=&HOUSE[0],
        .width=8,
        .height=8,
        .player={0, 0}, 
        .return_to=&village
    };

    village.portals[0] = &loc;

    return village;
}
```

this gets called in my `main()` function:

```
location current_location = build_locations();
```

And this works, up to a point - I can draw the `village` map and move the player around it:

```
display_map(&current_location);

display_player(&current_location);
```

and so on. The trouble comes when I want to swap into a new location.

If I try and reassign `current_location`, I get a compiler error complaining about `assignment to read only variable`:

```
current_location = current_location.portals[0];
```

This is easily the most complex code I've written in C, so I know I'm out of my depth when it comes to structures and pointers, but I'm trying to learn and I've come a long way already.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? Or is there something obvious I have missed?

Thanks

EDIT:

This is the most minimal example I can come up with:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

static const byte VILLAGE[] = {
      0,   0,   0,   0,  175, 181, 181, 181, 181, 181, 181, 175,   0,   0,   0,   0,
      /// And so on - indices of tiles defined elsewhere but irrelevant here
};

static const byte HOUSE[] = {
      0,   0,   0,   0,  175, 181, 181, 181, 181, 181, 181, 175,   0,   0,   0,   0,
      /// And so on - indices of tiles defined elsewhere but irrelevant here
};

typedef struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
} point;


typedef struct location {
    const point portal_in;
    const point portal_out;

    const byte *map;
    const byte width;
    const byte height;

    struct location *portals[8];

    point player;

    struct location *return_to;
} location; 

location build_locations()
{
    location village = { 
        .portal_in={15, 14}, 
        .portal_out={0, 0}, 
        .map=&VILLAGE[0],
        .width=32,
        .height=16,
        .player={15, 14}, 
        .return_to=0 
    };
    location loc = { 
        .portal_in={8, 7}, 
        .portal_out={11, 10}, 
        .map=&HOUSE[0],
        .width=8,
        .height=8,
        .player={0, 0}, 
        .return_to=&village
    };

    village.portals[0] = &loc;

    return village;
}

int main(void)
{
    location current_location = build_locations();

    if (current_location.player.x == 5 && current_location.player.y == 4)
    {
        current_location = current_location.portals[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some [MCVE] please

Comment: `current_location` should be a pointer to a location, and not a location in itself, if I understand this correctly.

Comment: That's what I thought, but if I make it a pointer, I get a different error `incompatible types when initializing` when setting it.

Comment: @MartinVéronneau - either that or just dereference `current_location.portals[0]`.

Comment: @SHG do you mean `current_location = *(current_location.portals[0]);`? That gives me the same read-only variable error.

Comment: @SHG he got const in structure members, so assignment will not work. need to `memcpy` or use pointers completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Runtime problem:*

Problem is simple. Both `village` and `loc` are on stack.

on return, you get a copy of `village`, but no copy for `loc`. so `loc` will be released after return. You can use a code like this to solve your problem:

```
village.portals[0] = calloc(1, sizeof(*(village.portals[0])));
memcpy(&village.portals[0], &loc, sizeof(loc)); //->or just assign village.portals[0] directly
```

**Update:**

*Compile problem*

Yea comments on `current_location` is correct too. You can solve it like this:

```
current_location = *(current_location.portals[0]);
```

or use pointers completely for accessing data.

But just remember runtime problem that I mentioned is very important and very hard to trace later too.

**Update 2:**

I just noticed that you have `const` members in your structure. that's why you get those `read-only` errors if you use assignment only. You can solve this problem by removing those `const`s from `location` structure or you can do it like this:

```
memcpy(&current_location, current_location.portals[0], sizeof(current_location));
```

but I don't suggest this approach, **it is better to use pointers** to prevent this problem.

Comment: That's a runtime problem, but the OP is complaining about a compile-time problem.

Comment: forgive my ignorance, but why doesn't `loc` get passed back along with the reference in `village.portals[0]`?

Comment: also, `current_location = *(current...` gives the same read-only variable error

Comment: @MalphasWats because c/c++ are not like java language that keep referenced data in memory. you get a copy of `village` by value, but you are accessing `loc` by another pointer so you will not get a copy of it.

Comment: @Afshin I see, thank you! That would have taken me a while to track down once I get it compiling!

Comment: @Afshin Ah, that makes sense - removing the const compiles but gives a warning because the maps are defined as constant by necessity as they're stored in PROGMEM on the AVR I'm using. I want to use your "full pointer" suggestion but not sure where to start.

Comment: @MalphasWats in your `build_location()` method, allocate memory for localtion by `malloc` and return pointer to this structure for your `current_location`. now you need to use pointer for accessing this structure everywhere in your code. when you want to no to portal, you can just assign portal pointer to your `current_location`, because now `current_location` is pointer too. working with pointers is more complex, but much more flexible and I think much better for you.

Comment: @Afshin hmm, ideally I need to avoid using `malloc()` on an AVR - I only have 512bytes total sram anyway! I tried declaring the locations up front but it didn't like that, complained about expecting a statement before {

Comment: @MalphasWats comments getting too long :). if you are using AVR and all your states are fixed (nothing is loaded dynamically), you can define all of your states as a global variable (for example all states defined as `static` **global** variables in single file. then return address of root element with a function and use it in other files. But you need to consider implications of using global variables. this way limits your flexibility, but in your AVR case,it may be ok. You will not need `malloc()` in this case.